# Angular 2 Token in Url unavailable in first call of GuardService

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have an angular 2 webapi application where users have to log in. I am now creating a `startpage` where users can view messages for their department when not yet logged in. The url, which users can get from within the application when logged in and set as their startpage, contains a token which is stored in the database and has a relation to their department.

I'm using a guard service to protect the `StartpageComponent` and to be able to check the token before allowing the user to go further. My routing file looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [{
        path: '',
        component: NavigationComponent,
        children: [{ 
            {
                path: 'messages',
                component: MessagesComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'startpage',
                canActivate: [TokenGuard],
                canActivateChild: [TokenGuard],
                component: StartpageComponent
            }
        }]
    }]
]
```

The `TokenGuard` calls the `StartpageService.validateToken` which in turn calls the webapi to validate the token. In the first call to the `StartpageService.validateToken` method from `TokenGuard` the `accessToken` is unavailable. In the second call however the token is available.
The following code is from my `TokenGuard` and `StartpageService`:

```
import {StartpageService} from 'startpage.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router,ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class TokenGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
    constructor(
        private startPageService: StartpageService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.startPageService.validateToken();
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }
}
```

`StartpageService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class StartpageService {
    private accessToken: string;
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) { 
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
            this.accessToken = params['token'];
            console.log(`START SERVICE CONSTRUCTOR TOKEN ${this.accessToken}`);
        });
    }

    public validateToken(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.startpaginaUrl}?token=${this.accessToken}`).map(res => {
            return <boolean>res.json();
        });
    }
}
```

Running this code results the following messages in my console:

```
START SERVICE CONSTRUCTOR TOKEN undefined
START SERVICE CONSTRUCTOR TOKEN 2CF37DCD065D2C7BBACFC4A7D71F1D27F6030A45DBBD243205144E1956D5F87F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartpageService` constructor is called too soon.

Read the token from the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and pass it to `validateToken` as a parameter.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    let token = route.queryParams['token'];
    return this.startPageService.validateToken(token);;
}
```

Comment: That was the solution. Funny thing is that `route.params['token']` is undefined

Comment: Yea, it's confusing. There's these `params` also: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter

e.g.
`{ path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }`
`localhost:3000/hero/15`

Comment: That's the example I was looking at as well.